# Methods for caching collections

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have tables in my database like: `Countries`, `Cities`, `Districts`, `BloodTypes`, `EyeColors` and so on.

All these tables have two columns: `ID` and `VALUE`. In my application users are searching through data. And for one search it must get `VALUE` column for an `ID`. I am using entity for retrieving data from the tables.

I want to query database once when application is started. I don't want to store data in client machine. What is the best way for such a scenario? I've read about Isolated Storage, also about [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7319). Is there  anything about *Entity Caching*?

Answer (score 0):

a very quick solution is executing the .ToArray linq extension method on a query object. then the query is exectued and the resulting objects are putted into a new array. this array is now in the memory and you can use it as cache

Comment: you mean to use static objects?

Comment: I have not catch you. I want a best method for handling such problem.